# How can I sort solr result bases on dynamic fields

Tags: solr, solrj, solr4, solrnet, solrcloud

I need to sort result on the basis of dynamic field.
How can I do that?
When I am sorting on minimum value of some of those dynamic attribute. It's not giving correct result because my query is like `&sort=min(A_160018,A_chandigarh1)` Some of document having both field `A_160018` and `A_chandigarh1`  while some document having no field and some having one either `A_160018` or `A_chandigarh1`  for some result doc.

How can I sort for this type of dynamic field?

Comment: Do you have an example where your existing sort is not giving the correct result?

Answer (score 4):

If you do not know if the field exist, you can set a default value in case it does not exists.

Try to use the **def** function, that returns a default vlaue if the field does not exist.

//in this part of query, I have put a default value that is very high in order to put the result on bottom of the list
    &sort=min(def(A_160018,9000000),def(A_chandigarh1,9000000))

Extract of solr def doc

> def(field|function,defaultValue) returns the value of field "field",
>   or if the field does not exist, returns the defaultValue specified.
>
> Example use: def(rating,5) The def() function will here return the
>   rating, or if no rating specified in the doc, returns 5

See [reference solr documentation](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery#field)